# Android camera preview callback and mediarecorder record video

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I want to create an application,that has to record video (using media recorder) and recorded video need to format(using camera).
I created sample code shown below, but that have an error show when the startrecording button press from menu.which shows force close error .but previewcallback have no error.   My code shown below

```
  package buffer.video;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import java.io.IOException;  
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class VofoVideoToBufferActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
    Camera.AutoFocusCallback {

    private SurfaceView preview;
    private SurfaceHolder previewHolder;

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
    private boolean mCaptureFrame = false;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("", "Begin onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(this);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


    }


    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    }


    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
    }

    public void startRecording() {
    Log.e("", "Begin StartRecording");
    mCaptureFrame = true;

    if(mRecorder!=null)
    {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
    }
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
    mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
    mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);


    mRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000);

    mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder.getSurface());
    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videotest2.3gp");
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mRecorder.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
    Log.e("", "Begin StopChange");
    mRecorder.stop();
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.startRecording:
       startRecording();

        return true;
    case R.id.stopRecording:
        stopRecording();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    }


    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e("", "Begin surfaceDestroy");
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = false;
    mCamera.release();

    mRecorder.reset();
    mRecorder.release();
    }


    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {


    }


    PreviewCallback previewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Log.e("", "onPreviewFrame pass");
        if (mCaptureFrame) {
        Toast.makeText(getParent(),"halooo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
    };


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Log.e("", "Begin SurfaceChange");



    if (mPreviewRunning)
        mCamera.stopPreview();

    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
     p.setPreviewSize(170,240);

    mCamera.setParameters(p);

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);

    mCamera.startPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = true;

    }

    }
```

Manifestfile show below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="vofo.streaming"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Logcat view shown below.Logcat last portion only copied.

```
07-19 12:42:42.229: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8599): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7 objects / 408168 bytes in 236ms
07-19 12:42:42.259: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:42.339: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:42.469: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:42.589: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:42.709: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:43.089: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8599): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7 objects / 408168 bytes in 258ms
07-19 12:42:43.099: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:43.169: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:43.289: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:43.419: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:43.439: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=vofo.streaming/.MainActivity }
07-19 12:42:43.629: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8802): Shutting down VM
07-19 12:42:43.679: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8802): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-19 12:42:43.809: INFO/AndroidRuntime(8802): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-19 12:42:43.841: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Start proc vofo.streaming for activity vofo.streaming/.MainActivity: pid=8811 uid=10036 gids={1015, 1006, 3003}
07-19 12:42:43.850: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:44.479: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8599): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 15 objects / 408680 bytes in 566ms
07-19 12:42:44.499: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:44.589: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:44.719: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:44.859: ERROR/(8599): onPreviewFrame pass
07-19 12:42:45.859: VERBOSE/RecordVideo(8811): Width x Height = 176x144
07-19 12:42:45.949: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Displayed activity vofo.streaming/.MainActivity: 2317 ms (total 2317 ms)
07-19 12:42:46.599: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8599): Shutting down VM
07-19 12:42:46.599: WARN/dalvikvm(8599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at buffer.video.VofoVideoToBufferActivity.surfaceDestroyed(VofoVideoToBufferActivity.java:128)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.SurfaceView.reportSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:568)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:472)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:206)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:3891)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:719)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:744)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 12:42:48.049: DEBUG/dalvikvm(181): GC_EXPLICIT freed 191 objects / 13008 bytes in 8398ms
07-19 12:42:52.690: INFO/Process(8599): Sending signal. PID: 8599 SIG: 9
07-19 12:42:52.750: INFO/ActivityManager(67): Process buffer.video (pid 8599) has died.
07-19 12:42:52.759: INFO/WindowManager(67): WIN DEATH: Window{4509e720 SurfaceView paused=false}
07-19 12:42:52.790: INFO/WindowManager(67): WIN DEATH: Window{4507e048 buffer.video/buffer.video.VofoVideoToBufferActivity paused=false}
07-19 12:42:52.880: WARN/InputManagerService(67): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45061a50
07-19 12:42:56.730: DEBUG/dalvikvm(262): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31 objects / 1576 bytes in 169ms
07-19 12:43:00.439: ERROR/CameraInput(34): Unsupported parameter(x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value)
07-19 12:43:00.439: ERROR/CameraInput(34): VerifiyAndSetParameter failed on parameter #0
07-19 12:43:00.460: ERROR/audio_input(34): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
07-19 12:43:00.469: ERROR/audio_input(34): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
07-19 12:43:00.539: WARN/AuthorDriver(34): Video encoding bit rate is set to 192000 bps
07-19 12:43:00.589: INFO/MediaRecorderJNI(8811): prepare: surface=0x20fc70 (id=1)
07-19 12:43:00.649: ERROR/PVOMXEncNode(34): PVMFOMXEncNode-Audio_AMRNB::DoPrepare(): Got Component OMX.PV.amrencnb handle 
07-19 12:43:00.699: DEBUG/CameraHardwareStub(34): initHeapLocked: preview size=320x240
07-19 12:43:00.759: DEBUG/CameraInput(34): Intended mFrameWidth=176, mFrameHeight=144 
07-19 12:43:00.759: DEBUG/CameraHardwareStub(34): initHeapLocked: preview size=176x144
07-19 12:43:00.779: DEBUG/CameraInput(34): Actual mFrameWidth=176, mFrameHeight=144 
07-19 12:43:00.799: ERROR/AuthorDriver(34): Command 13 completed with error -17
07-19 12:43:00.799: ERROR/MediaRecorder(8811): prepare failed: -17
07-19 12:43:00.799: ERROR/RecordVideo(8811): java.io.IOException: prepare failed.
07-19 12:43:00.799: WARN/System.err(8811): java.io.IOException: prepare failed.
07-19 12:43:00.850: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
07-19 12:43:00.859: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:503)
07-19 12:43:00.869: WARN/System.err(8811):     at vofo.streaming.MainActivity.beginRecording(MainActivity.java:191)
07-19 12:43:00.869: WARN/System.err(8811):     at vofo.streaming.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:162)
07-19 12:43:00.899: WARN/System.err(8811):     at vofo.streaming.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
07-19 12:43:00.899: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-19 12:43:00.899: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-19 12:43:00.899: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-19 12:43:00.919: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 12:43:00.919: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-19 12:43:00.959: WARN/System.err(8811):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-19 12:43:00.959: WARN/System.err(8811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 12:43:00.969: WARN/System.err(8811):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-19 12:43:00.969: WARN/System.err(8811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-19 12:43:00.969: WARN/System.err(8811):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-19 12:43:00.989: WARN/System.err(8811):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Either `mCamera` or `mRecorder` is null in your method `onSurfaceDestroyed`. Check for null and do the operation on these objects only if it is not null.

Comment: thanks for your help.but my error not get after onSurFaceDestroyed. Error only get when the startRecording() method will call.

Comment: but your logcat log `
07-19 12:42:46.669: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8599):     at buffer.video.VofoVideoToBufferActivity.surfaceDestroyed(VofoVideoToBufferActivity.java:128)
` says otherwise..

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line:

```
mRecorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call
     mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder.getSurface());
after the surface is created.
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e("", "Begin surfaceDestroy");
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder.getSurface());
    }

Answer (score 0):

Solution a:
You can change method startrecording() to:

```
    private void startrecording(){

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();

    }
    mMediaRecorder.start();
}
```